# Why does Rainbow Dash refer to herself as a billy?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony

In the episode Sonic Rainboom, right near the start you hear Rainbow Dash refer to herself as a 'Billy'?

The only reference I can find to this is a 'male goat'.

Why would she say that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's actually "filly" (a young, female, horse):

> TWILIGHT SPARKLE: What's a sonic rainboom?
>
> PINKIE PIE: You really need to get out more. The sonic rainboom is legendary! When a Pegasus like Rainbow Dash gets going soo fast... BOOM! A sonic boom and a rainbow can happen all at once!
>
> APPLEJACK: And Rainbow Dash here's the only pony to ever pull it off!
>
> RAINBOW DASH: It was a long time ago... I was just a **filly**.
>
> PINKIE PIE: Yeah, but you're gonna do it again, right?
>
> RAINBOW DASH: Are... you kidding? I'm the greatest flyer to ever come out of Cloudsdale! I could do sonic rainbooms in my sleep.

Comment: For some reason, @thedaian hasn't added this as an answer (see the comments on the question), even though it's correct.  We want the answer to be an answer, so I've added it, but it's community wiki so no rep for me.  thedaian: if you like, copy my answer into one of your own, comment here, and I'll delete mine.